# How to disabled inline-script in Nuxt3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

I would like to know if there is a way to instruct Nuxt not to include inline script tags. Instead, I would like all the JavaScript code to be placed in separate .js files. Currently, when I view the page source, I can see the JavaScript code embedded within inline script tags. I would like to disable this feature.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to separate this?

Comment: I basically implement CSP using nuxt-security module. Now every time the inline-script is change I need to add a hash that's why is there is no inline-script then no need to add hash again and again. Maybe there is a better way to deal this type of situation but unfortunately i don't know about the other ways

Comment: Ah okay, it seems you're trying to do something "hacky/dirty" in relation to security which is very dangerous. I don't know the solution but you can maybe ask here for guidance: https://github.com/Baroshem/nuxt-security/issues